# Classify files in a directory structure YYYY-MM-DD, with Script in Automator, getting it from their filenames

Tags: bash, macos, shell, automator

Having media (pictures and videos) without meta-data date, but are named with this date structure (YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg/ .mov/ .png...), I'm trying to classify them in folders named as their date, YYYY-MM-DD.

My bash version in Mac:
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

My type -ap bash: bash is /bin/bash

I was trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dest_dir=/Users/myuser/photo-archive
for file in /Users/myuser/photo-archive/Blackhole/*.jpg; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue  # look at regular files only
  if [[ $file =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]; then
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    destination_dir=$dest_dir/$year-$month-$day
    mkdir -p "$destination_dir"
    echo "Moving $file to $destination_dir"
    mv "$file" "$destination_dir"
  fi
done
```

But I do not get anything.

Any idea where could be the error? I'm super lost.

Thanks

Comment: You set a variable `dest_dir=/Users/myuser/photo-archive` but then on the next line hard-code the directory path again `for file in /Users/myuser/photo-archive/Blackhole/*.jpg; do`. Use your variable - `for file in "$dest_dir"/Blackhole/*.jpg; do`

Comment: Having 1 variable named `dest_dir` and another named `destination_dir` could get confusing and make it easy to introduce bugs. What you're currently calling `dest_dir` looks like it might be better named `base_dir` or similar as it seems to be the base for the directories you're copying from and to.

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting that `file` contains the full path. The regex `^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})` won't match a string starting with `/Users/myuser/photo-archive/Blackhole/`.

Change that conditional to this and it'll work.

```
[[ ${file##*/} =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]
```

Comment: `if [[ \`filename $file\` =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]` should also work.

Comment: @Spencer copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about a couple of problems with it plus it's using an external non-standard tool unnecessarily. Do it as shown in the answer instead for robustness, portability and efficiency.

Comment: Alternatively `[[ $file =~ .*/([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]` to just prepend the regexp with `.*/` to match the directory path.

Comment: @EdMorton meh, I meant `\`basename\`` and have had the backticks ingrained into me.

Comment: I have to test it properly, and I'll confirm you, but it looks like with the conditional Oguz Ismail said, it's working. This one: 
`[[ ${file##*/} =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]`

Thank you very much to all of you!!

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! So many months trying to make it work and finally I can organise it.
A couple of questions: - If I add duplicates, which one it keeps? (older, newer of creation..) - Would it be easy to add one more level? YYYYMM and inside that level the days as it is? Just wondering...